# wordpress - Rewrite post permalink

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I've a custom post type that it can view on mywebsite.com/custom_post_type/ (with archive.php), but I don't understand how change permalink of "post" (default type - articles).
This is what I need:
I want to read all "post" with this url: mywebsite.com/news/. "News" would the slug for "post" type.

I think it's necessary to rewrite the permalink, but I didn't found anything on google.

Can you help me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your questions but I think you are trying to do is view all 'Posts' under mywebsite.com/news/ - In that case simply create a page called News (with the slug/permalink as news) and then in Settings > Reading - set the Front page to 'A static page', with the front page selecting your 'Home' page and the Posts page set as 'News' (the page you just made).

If you are talking about viewing all posts of a custom post type under news, either name the post type slug (under your rewrite array setting when you register the CPT) as News.

Comment: Yes you understand my question! Yours is a good solution, but I want to use the same file (archive.php) that I'm using for other custom post type!

Comment: Ok, just copy the code from the archive.php into your index.php file as that's the default template file used for blog listing pages